# Fetching list data from malformed HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to fetch data from a `<UL>` where the list data is malformed. In other words the end tags (`</LI>`) are missing in the list:

```
<UL>
    <LI>Blah2
    <LI><A>Blah</A>
    <LI><A>Blah2</A>
</UL>

<UL>
    <LI><A>Blah</A>
    <LI>Blah2
    <LI><A>Blah2</A>
</UL>

<UL>
    <LI><A>Blah</A>
</UL>

<UL>
    <LI>Blah
</UL>
```

Can i somehow iterate through this? As shown in the example there can be a mixture of links and no links. Whats most important is that i fetch the links (if any) and text.

Unfortunately BeutifulSoup attempts to repair the malformed HTML and causes more damage than needed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
html = '<UL><LI>Blah><LI><A>Blah</A><LI><A>Blah2</A></UL>'
print bsoup(html).prettify()
>>> <ul>
>>>  <li>
>>>   Blah&gt;
>>>   <li>
>>>    <a>
>>>     Blah
>>>    </a>
>>>    <li>
>>>     <a>
>>>      Blah2
>>>     </a>
>>>    </li>
>>>   </li>
>>>  </li>
>>> </ul>
```

As seen on the example above Bsoup is adding all end tags in the end of the list items.

Comment: N.b.: that's [allowed in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), but BS doesn't recover the way the standard says it should.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, so basically its a BS bug?

Comment: Depending on your parser, [BS handles invalid HTML differently](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: `html5lib` did the trick.

Comment: @JavaCake Great. I'll add my comment as a proper answer for reference and closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, [BS4 handles invalid HTML differently depending on which parser you use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers). The [four parsers that are supported](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) are:

- html.parser (which is built in)
- lxml's HTML parser
- lxml's XML parser
- html5lib (which works in this case)

You can use trial and error or look specifically at your issue and the way each parser handles it (using the links above) and choose a parser that acts in the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no nested list items, you can manually close the `<li>` tags using regular expressions:

```
>>> xhtml = re.sub(r'\<li\>(.*?)(?=\<li\>)', r'<li>\1</li>', html, 
...                flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
>>> xhtml
'<UL><li>Blah></li><li><A>Blah</A></li><LI><A>Blah2</A></UL>'
>>> print(BeautifulSoup(xhtml).prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>
    Blah&gt;
   </li>
   <li>
    <a>
     Blah
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a>
     Blah2
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your example and it works on the HTML sample, but when i fire it into my entire HTML document it converts the lists to something like this: `</li><li><A HREF="#">Lorem ipsum</A>`

Comment: @JavaCake I cannot comment unless i see the actual html you are working with